# Backbone.js view + underscore.js templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a div container element and inside this container element I have multiple templates. I want to selectively load templates based on the json returned from backend. It's a trivial problem but facing issues doing this. Some logical code.

```
<div id = "container">
  <div class = "row page">
    <script type = "text/template" id = "template1">
      <div id = "template1_id">
      </div>
    </script>
    <script type = "text/template" id = "template2">
      <div id = "template2_id">
      </div>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my Backbone View I'm doing something like:

```
var someView = Backbone.view.extend({
  el: '.page'
  render: function() {
    el: '.page';
    var template1 = _.template($('#template1').html());
    this.$el.html(template1);
    //get Json from backend and render the template within the fetch method
    var collection1 = new someCollection();
    someCollection.url = "blah";
    someCollection.fetch ( function() {
      success: function() {
        var template2 = _.template($('#template2').html());
        $('#template1_id').html(template2);
      }
    });

  },
});
```

Only the first template is rendered and not the second one. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rendering both of the templates into one container, you should be using `$.append`, rather than `$.html`, so both will be appended consequently.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo(mismatched quote)

```
$('#template1_id").html(template2);
```

should be

```
$("#template1_id").html(template2);
```

Comment: Hey thanks - I fixed that but the issue still persists. I'm debugging as we speak.